# need help installing the program image (BIN-file) to the imx6s device

Tags: yocto

how to include a ready-made compiled BIN-file ((native application of the application program) in the recipe YOCTO Project.
OR
how to install a ready-made compiled BIN file of an application program to a target device in Flash-memory from under u-boot or from under Linux

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to know how to burn a Yocto image into a flash drive?

If so, you should use the dd command as described in this guide:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html

```
 4. Write the Image: You can write the image just built to a bootable media (e.g. a USB key, SATA drive, SD card, etc.) using the dd utility:

     $ sudo dd if=tmp/deploy/images/intel-corei7-64/core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.wic of=TARGET_DEVICE
```